# How to: MySQLi to PDO

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

I have code that uses MySQLi for access to the database and I want to change to PDO Statement, anyone can help? There's my code:

```
function select_data($user_id, $start_date, $end_date)
{
    global $connection;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM attendancy
        WHERE user_id = $user_id
        AND date >= '$start_date'
        AND date <= '$end_date'";

    $result = $connection->query($sql);
    if(!is_object($result)) return array();

    $data = array();

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $row['duration'] = count_work_hours($row);
        $data[] = $row;
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: `mysqli` is also good if you use parameterized format

Comment: I have, but doesnt work

Comment: @pranatayudha So you haven't done it right. And if you're not able to use them with mysqli, I'm quite sure you'll fail with PHP too. So instead of trying to change everything to PDO directly, why you don't show us your code when you tried so use prepared statements with mysqli, and we help you to find your errors? To change this to PDO you can simply google. We're here to help, not to write code for you. If you have been able to write this code in mysqli, you're able to write it with PDO too, no need to ask us for that. But as I said, show us your prepared statements, will help you more :)

Comment: I want share my PDO code, but too long

Comment: Why is your PDO code too long? The required number of lines for a PDO query doesn't significantly differ from other APIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function select_data($user_id, $start_date, $end_date)
{
    global $connection;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM attendancy
        WHERE user_id = :user_id
        AND date >= :start_date
        AND date <= :end_date";

    $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql,[PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY]);

    $stmt->execute([":user_id" => $user_id, ":start_date" => $start_date, ":end_date" => $end_date]);

    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);        

    if(!count($results)){
        return array();
    }
    else{

        $data = array();

        foreach($results as $row){

            $row['duration'] = count_work_hours($row);
            $data[] = $row;
        }
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: thanks, it's solved! @Eng Cy

Comment: Nope, Glad to help